# Should I indicate in the title that the question was self-answered?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, title

Have you encountered cases where knowing that the question has already been answered would be beneficial? I recently posted such a question, and got a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118297/skip-after-commit-on-destroy/38118298#comment63669028_38118297) which I think could have been avoided if it was clear that it's self-answered.

I'm not sure if it should be in the title or in the body. IMHO, if such indication is indeed needed, the best option would be some SE-wide visual markup.

Comment: Wow. The comment on your question, *and* the comment on your self-answer. What is "Add comment and accept your answer" even supposed to mean?!

Comment: The site already makes it abundantly clear that your question has a self-answer - by the fact that your answer has your usercard highlighted in blue just as with the question. People are just that boneheaded. Some people even think answering your own question is against the rules and go so far as to *flag* self-answers for moderator attention.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A-style code repository. Whether a question is self-answered is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @BoltClock That comment on the answer is indeed messed up, but the comment on the question is entirely appropriate.  That the question is self answered in no way changes the standard of quality for the question; that response is just as appropriate for a self-answer as it is for a non-self answered question.  Asking a question trivially solved by reading the documentation, and with lots of other relevant sources that are readily accessible, is a bad question, whether self answered or not.

Comment: @Braiam, I reverted your edit since my question was referring to **instant** self answers.

Comment: From the system point of view there is no difference between answering "instantly" and 3 years after. We do not treat them differently either.

Comment: Indeed, but I just wanted to have the right tag.

Comment: Related: we don't want `[solved]` or other similar meta-information in titles. In other sites such as forums it is considered polite behaviour, here we prefer users do _not_ do this.

Comment: In light of @Servy's answer, I wonder why the usercard is highlighted in blue.

Comment: And as you can see by Servy's answer, doesn't matter when you answered it, he in fact ignores the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We don't *want* people to treat questions any differently when they're self answered.  It's problematic when they *do* treat them differently.

It's no more appropriate to ask a poorly researched question when self-answering than it is to ask a poorly researched question that's already well covered in the documentation when you're expecting others to answer.

While you may be right that the comment you've linked to was posted by someone who didn't realize you self answered, their indication of the problem with your question is *still entirely valid*.  Were someone to excuse these problems with the question as a result of your answer then such a fictional person would be the one not doing what we want.

Answer (score 5):

As everything else, the system already has tools to make apparent who answered the question. In the case of self-answered, the user-card and name of the OP have a different background to differentiate them. There's absolutely no need to indicate that a) is self answered or b) that is answered. Everyone can see if a question is answered from almost any place: [the search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby-on-rails]%20[ruby]%20[activerecord]%20user%3A165753%20is%3Aq), the [question list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails%20ruby%20activerecord?mode=all) or tag page. Also, it doesn't matter when you self answered it, the editorial rules apply all the same.

Comment: `the rules apply all the same.` Not exactly. Accepted answers to self aren't pinned to the top, i.e they'll move down if outvoted by other answers.

Comment: @dorukayhan editorial rules I mean